# How to enable target="_black" from IFRAME in VSCode Webview

Tags: webview, vscode-extensions

When I use the iframe in VSCode's WebView, popups are disabled by default. That is if you have an anchor tag with target="_black", it will not open a new browser.
Is there any way to resolve this problem?

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('openWebview',
'Title',
vscode.ViewColumn.One,
{
    enableScripts: true
});
panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
....
....
function getWebviewContent() {
    return `<iframe src="http://localhost:8080/homepage" title="Title"></iframe>`;
}
```

The homepage has some external references which use the anchor tag

```
<a href="https://owasp.org" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">OWASP</a>
```

If I click this link within the iFrame nothing happens. I wanted to open the link in an external web browser.

Thanks you

Comment: try <a href="#" onClick="window.open('http://www.yahoo.com', '_blank')">test</a>

Comment: Thanks @abhinavxeon, I tried ` onClick="window.open('yahoo.com', '_blank')"`,  but not working. As I mentioned, it seems like a restriction in the VSCode Webview when using iframe.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a straight solution. There is a restriction in the VS code Webview. Hence, the only solution I can think about is to add a message support in your html page.
Basically, when you click on a link we will send a message event to the parent frame which can be captured in the in the WebView.

For example, HTML page should be updated as

```
<a href="https://owasp.org" rel="noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"
  onClick="window.parent.postMessage(this.href, '*')">OWASP</a>
```

And in VS code plugin,

```
const panel = vscode.window.createWebviewPanel('openWebview',
    'Title', vscode.ViewColumn.One, { enableScripts: true });

panel.webview.onDidReceiveMessage(
  message => {
     switch (message.command) {
            case 'show':
              vscode.env.openExternal(vscode.Uri.parse(message.text));
              return;
          }
        },
        undefined,
        context.subscriptions
      );
    panel.webview.html = getWebviewContent();
});
...
...
function getWebviewContent() {
  return `<script> 
    window.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
      const vscode = acquireVsCodeApi();
      vscode.postMessage({command: 'show', text: e.data});
    }, false);
    </script>
    <iframe src=" http://localhost:8080/homepage" ></iframe>`;
}
```